# How can I mix knockout observable and computed

Tags: knockout.js

I have a knockout observable defined in one place of the code (Typescript).

```
title: KnockoutObservableBase<string>;
```

In another class I have 2 places where I update the title. The first place is with static string:

```
title("Loading...")
```

And in later I want to put calculated string. Something like

```
pureComputed(a + b);
```

I am not sure how to do it. I cannot do `title(pureComputed())` and I cannot re-assign the parameter.

I have read a bit about writable computable, but I am not sure if it is relevant.

**Update**
This is a code sample of what I would like to happen: http://jsfiddle.net/tu97bz0b/

1. "Loading" should change to computed value after 1 second - works
2. "Sky King" should change to "Sky Queen" after 2 more seconds - does not work

```js
var viewModel = {
    firstName: ko.observable("Sky"),
    lastName: ko.observable("King"),
};

viewModel.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
    return viewModel.firstName() + " " + viewModel.lastName();
});

viewModel.test =  ko.observable();
viewModel.test("Loading");
setTimeout(function() {
 viewModel.test(viewModel.fullName());
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
 viewModel.lastName("Queen");
}, 3000);

// This makes Knockout get to work
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: can you address your issue with a sample, tough you can added computed value to observable http://jsfiddle.net/eK3KA/198/

Comment: @supercool I have updated the question - I hope it is more clear

Comment: it works still you missed updating `test` check this http://jsfiddle.net/tu97bz0b/1/

Comment: @supercool but I thought that the all point of using computed values. That I don't need to update test directly

Comment: you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/47912/ best way to do .

Comment: hope you're clear now, yes'dy i gotta rush so not able add detailed exp and added some basic sample .

Comment: I suspected I would have to use writable computables. I hoped for easier way.

Comment: well there can be a easy way for sure if you see `title("Loading...")` & why you want to put up static thing in first place and also again you trying to assign a computed value to `title` again . you can always have a plain function(performance wise better) gives you the computed response when requested . As everything is observable our work is made easier .